# TeeChart Zoom and Panning Issue

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a dilemma.  I am using the TeeChart in both zoom and panning mode.

When I pan the zoomed image to the right, I want the image to stay in its current horizontal position when I undo the zoom condition.  However, when I do Chart1.UndoZoom, the image resets itself back to the left axis edge.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Zoom.History:

```
  Chart1.Zoom.History := True;
```

This doesn't work combined with panning though. In which case, you could save desired axes minimum and maximum positions in *OnZoom* event and restore them in *OnUndoZoom* event.